# Which version of Firefox Nightly should I install?

Tags: android, firefox, cpu-architecture, fennec, nightly-build

I have a [Samsung Galaxy S3](http://www.samsung.com/es/galaxys3/specifications.html), but I really don't understand about mobile architectures. Anybody can explain me?

I need to install Fennex on my Android, but I don't know which of [these two versions](http://nightly.mozilla.org/) should I install.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is not a programming question and therefore off topic here on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Fennec is what I need to run my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Samsung Galaxy S3 is an ARMv7 device, so you must install Android Version which not mentioned ARM version.

Comment: Ahmad is right, this is a programming community, you can ask your android devices and softwares questions in http://forum.xda-devlopers.com

Comment: It's about installing my programming environment